# How to send informations to RFT playback window when running scripts?

Tags: java, automated-tests, rft

When Rational Functional Tester runs a script, it shows the current script name, line number, and method.

[image: Rational Functional Tester Playback window]

When I run my own code or external tools, line number and method name remain empty.

How to send these informations to the playback window?
I have some time-consuming jobs (checks on PDFs, database I/O, file transfers over network) and would like to update the status (the method name) at the beginning of each small job, to be sure that things are proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
 IPlaybackMonitor pbMonitor = (IPlaybackMonitor)ServiceBroker.getServiceBroker().findService(IPlaybackMonitor.class.getName());
    if ( pbMonitor != null )
        pbMonitor.setDescription(IPlaybackMonitor.RUNNING, "MyTestCode");
```